How to log out of Clerk OAuth session?
I have a Django application and I'm trying to authenticate users with Clerk as an OAuth2 provider (see Use Clerk as an OAuth 2 Provider for reference). I'm using authlib to help with the flow, and here is what I have in my views class:
from authlib.integrations.django_client import OAuth

oauth = OAuth()
client = oauth.register(
    'clerk',
    client_id=os.environ.get('CLERK_CLIENT_ID'),
    client_secret=os.environ.get('CLERK_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    client_kwargs={
        'scope': 'profile email',
    },
    server_metadata_url=f'https://{os.environ["CLERK_DOMAIN"]}/.well-known/openid-configuration',
)

I can handle the login with:
def login_oauth(request: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse:
    return client.authorize_redirect( # type: ignore
        request, request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('callback'))
    ) 

In the callback, I authorize the token and start a session in my application. However, I'm stuck trying to figure out how to "log out". I can obviously control the session on my server, but I'm not sure how I can revoke the Clerk session and effectively log them out of there. In the callback, Clerk passes the access and refresh tokens which I can use to get the user info, but I don't have a "session token" that I can use to revoke the Clerk session.
Most other OAuth providers I've worked with provide a logout URL (for example, Auth0 provides a v2/logout endpoint that I can call). I don't see anything in the Clerk documentation for logging out.
